# Convert HTML form to PDF

Tags: ruby, pdf-generation, prawn

How do I convert a html form to PDF. I would like to use Prawn for the purpose.

Pointing to any relevant links or examples would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to limit yourself to a technology (Prawn) not appropriate to the task (it's not geared towards using HTML to generate the PDF)?

You might want to check out [PDFKit](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit) instead, as it seems specifically designed to create PDFs from HTML, using powerful existing libraries.

Super short version (two lines!):

```ruby
kit = PDFKit.new("http://google.com")
kit.to_file('/path/to/save/google.pdf')
```

Read more about it here:
http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2010/06/15/rethinking-pdf-creation-in-ruby.html

Check out the RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit

Comment: …or, if you're using Ruby on Rails, perhaps check out [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf).

Comment: sorry Phrogz :) I was just typing away.. didn't see that you suggested that too.   +1

Comment: I added the RailsCasts link to your answer and deleted my answer